# what the difference between querstring payload in a post params?

Tags: python-requests

I am confused by the params in firefox developer->network->Params,
it has two type params(query string and Request Payload).what the difference between them,and how can I get right response with python requests module?

Answer (score 0):

**Query string**: parameters passed in the url of GET requests.

```
http://domain.com/page?PARAM1=VALUE1&PARAM2=VALUE2
```

you can send GET requests with pyhton method [*requests.get(...)*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

**Request payload**: parameters passed internally by the HTTP protocol, in the POST requests. You can send POST requests with the pyhton method [*requests.post(...)*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

Take a look at the requests documentation

Comment: requests.post(...,params,data,json,...);